# Can someone make a neder [vow] not to have any benefit from the area near the exit of someone else's house while he is in that house?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, nedarim-shevuot, real-estate

**If a person invites someone into his house, and the invitee makes a neder [vow] not to have any benefit [ מודר הנאה] from any area near an exit of his  host's house,  Is the neder valid. If so, can he leave the house, if he may not tread on the floor near the exit?**

Is there any source in halacha which says that a neder which infringes on another person's rights is not a valid neder?

Comment: Is the neder only on a specific exit, or all exits?

Comment: @DonielF Any and all exits

Comment: I'm sure vows that adversely affect another must be discussed in _halacha_. (For example — not that this is directly relevant — one criterion iirc for the ability to cancel a wife's vow is that it affects the husband.)

Comment: How does this infringe on someone else's rights? It's your problem how to leave the house not the owner's.

Comment: @DoubleAA Obviously the host does not want him to stay there forever, so the neder infringes on the personal privacy and ownership rights of the host.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Who said anything about staying forever? Kick him out. It's his problem not yours.

Comment: @DoubleAA Kick him out physically? What about "LO SACHILUM" - The prohibition against feeding someone something which is forbidden to him? If he is indeed forbidden by his neder to leave, then kicking him out would be Lo Sachilum.